# Trying to write formatted text back to Latex

Tags: lua, latex, docx, pandoc

I wrote a filter in LUA to add some styles when I convert a docx file in Latex. I got all working, but when I try to write the content of the paragraph the format is gone. I used stringify, but this deletes all the format.
Here is the filter I used:

```
function Div(el)

local startstyle="\\begin{"
local endstyle="\\end{"

styletobe=tostring(el.attr)
    divbe=tostring(el.t)

if (divbe=="Div" and (string.find(styletobe, "Claims") or string.find(styletobe, "Issues"))) then
    
    
    something=el.content
    --something=pandoc.walk_block(el, {
    --   Str = function(el) 
    --         return pandoc.Str(el.text)
    --    end })
        for key, value in pairs(something) do print(key, value) end     

        if string.find(styletobe, "Claims") then startstyle=startstyle.."claims}" endstyle=endstyle.."claims}" end 
        if string.find(styletobe, "Issues") then startstyle=startstyle.."issues}" endstyle=endstyle.."issues}" end 
     
        stylecontent=pandoc.utils.stringify(something)
        styleall= startstyle..stylecontent..endstyle.. "%%this is a style from word"
        print(something.content)
                print(el.t, "we got a claim!"..stylecontent)

    return pandoc.RawInline("latex", styleall)
    end

end
```

I am curious how can i convert a text like this:

```
Para [Str "Progress",Space,Str "is",Space,Str "a",Space,Str "function",Space,Str "of",Space,Strong [Str "creativity"],Space,Str "as",Space,Str "a",Space,Emph [Str "distributed"],Space,Str "property",Space,Str "over",Space,Str "a",Space,Str "result",Space,Str "and",Space,Str "environments."]
```

Into plain text with formatting.
Thanks!

See above code! I tried to add some style information from docx to latex